# Script para desplegar aplicación sencilla de Node.js en Elastic Beanstalk (aws)

Tags: nodejs, aws

Desplegué una aplicación que corre en Node.js en Heroku, simplemente añadiendo en el **package.json** lo siguiente:

```
 "scripts": {
"heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix front && npm run build --prefix front",
"heroku config":"set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true"
```

Ahora quiero desplegar la misma app en AWS, había pensado usar el servicio Elastic Beanstalk para hacer más sencillo el proceso.

Mi pregunta es, que es lo que tengo que cambiar de esos dos comandos para que en vez de en Heroku funcione en AWS?

No me hace falta base de datos ni nada, sólo que corra esos dos comandos al hacer el build para que funcione.

Comparto el repo que usa actualmente Heroku para servir mi app: https://github.com/Onpointiscake/shareable-todo/tree/testing-heroku

Comment: Hola, puedes indicarme que tipo de "aplicación" comentas?. Si no tiene base de datos ni nada, es algo así como un script? Si la aplicación es algo así como un script que acepta unos parámetros de entrada y realiza su ejecución y luego termina, quizás te vale una función lambda. Esta acepta parametros de entrada y retorna una respuesta, normalmente en menos de 6000ms aunque esto puede configurarse e incluso mantenerla activa, pero te cobran por tiempo de ejecución. No he tocado todo AWS pero igual puedo ayudarte

Comment: Te valdría utilizar "serverless + funciones lambda"? Es bastante sencillo montar una aplicación

Comment: @Sergio Oh igual no me expliqué bien perdona. No estoy seguro si me funcionaría con lambda, ya que es una aplicación montada en React.js y usa una REST API en Node. El backend se conecta a una base de datos online (a un cluster online de MongoDB). Añado el código de la app en el OP

Comment: Ahora entiendo, voy a intentar darle una vuelta y te comento algo :)

Comment: @JavierCake, me parece que te esta faltando crear el archivo [`nodecommand.config`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html#create_deploy_nodejs_express.update)

Answer (score 1):

En realidad para un funcionamiento básico no necesitas nada más que tu archivo principal se llame `app.js`, `server.js` o que en el package.json tengas la instrucción `"start": "node archivo.js"`, para subir tu aplicación a Elastic Beanstalk de AWS necesitas hacer:

1. Instalar y configurar AWS Cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-cli
2. Instalar Elastic Beanstalk Cli, https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup

   - `aws --version` y `eb --version` para saber si están bien instalados.
3. Entrar a la carpeta de tu aplicación.
4. Ejecutar `eb init` y seleccionar las opciones de tu preferencia.
5. Crear una carpeta llamada `.ebextensions`.
6. Dentro esta carpeta crear un archivo de cualquier nombre pero con la extensión `.config` (pe. `installation.config`) con el siguiente contenido:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production

container_commands:
  01_node_preinstallation:
    command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install nodejs"
    leader_only: true
  02_frontend_installation:
    command: "npm install --prefix front && npm run build --prefix front"
    leader_only: true
```

La primera parte del script definirá las variables de entorno, en este caso el de producción; la segunda parte los scripts iniciales.

7. Ejecutar `eb create prod-stage` para subir tu aplicación a AWS EB.
8. Y `eb open` para abrir la url en un navegador.
9. Para subir actualizaciones usas el comando `eb deploy`.

Con eso deberías tener tu aplicación funcionando en AWS Elastic Beanstalk con las configuraciones básicas.

En lo personal una vez tuve problemas al iniciar los scripts iniciales con NodeJS, lo que hice fue subir todo incluyendo los `node_modules`.

Comment: Hola he llegado hasta el final, me dice todo esta Ok pero cuando entro al link aparece pantalla en blanco. Me sale el error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity). Y simplemente la direccion http://prod-stage.eba-ndbn2gsn.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/1 refiriendose al error. (también me sale error al favicon.ico pero imagino que eso dará igual, igualmente lo borre y sigue saliendo).

Comment: Tienes razón, sí son necesarios los scripts de Heroku que mencionas, ahí edité mi respuesta con esos scripts, AWS puede ser un poco lioso al principio pero tienes mayor control sobre los recursos que Heroku :)

Comment: Oh, añadí eso y ahora me da error al desplegar: Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "app-0492-200307_124513" (deployment 4).
 . Creo que lo tengo exactamente como me dijiste https://github.com/Onpointiscake/shareable-todo/tree/aws-deploy

Comment: Ayer bajé el código para probar y en efecto da varios errores, lo raro es que no puedo hacer funcionar ni siquiera en local pero sí entrando al EC2 que crea Beanstalk y ejecutando manualmente los comandos `npm install` y `npm build`, si logras ejecutar automáticamente esos comandos sin error no olvides compartirlo por acá.